# Rails render does not render my new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an ajax request that hits a Rails Controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json, :html

  def my_method
    #logic happens here to produce an instance variable
    render template: 'other/template', layout: 'application'
  end
end
```

The logic is hit, and the rails console displays:

```
Rendered other/template.html.haml within layouts/application (34.8ms)
```

However, the browser does not update the DOM. What am I missing? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Your AJAX code has to process the response and insert it into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write my_method.js.erb file and instead of template create partial like other/_template.html.erb.
In my_method.js.erb write following code:

```
$("#ID").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'other/template')%>");

class MyController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json, :html

  def my_method
    #logic happens here to produce an instance variable
  end
end
```

Please not that #ID is the DOM element where you want to replace partial result.